# Is there an algorithm to multiply square matrices in-place?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, graphics, language-agnostic, linear-algebra

The naive algorithm for multiplying 4x4 matrices looks like this:

```c
void matrix_mul(double out[4][4], double lhs[4][4], double rhs[4][4]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
            out[i][j] = 0.0;
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; ++k) {
                out[i][j] += lhs[i][k] * rhs[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, this algorithm gives bogus results if `out == lhs` or `out == rhs` (here `==` means reference equality).  Is there a version that allows one or both of those cases that doesn't simply copy the matrix?  I'm happy to have different functions for each case if necessary.

I found [this](https://www.google.ca/search?q=winoschedule.pdf) paper but it discusses the Strassen-Winograd algorithm which is overkill for my small matrices.  The answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1167852/502399) question seem to indicate that if `out == lhs && out == rhs` (i.e., we're attempting to square the matrix), then it can't be done in place, but even there there's no convincing evidence or proof.

Comment: I personally find quite obvious that you can't do it in place without caching some values. try doing it by hand on paper, erasing with a rubber the numbers in either `lhs` or `rhs` when you want to write the result.

Comment: @flebool That's true, but even caching a single row/column at a time could be better than copying the whole matrix.

Comment: Strassen-Winograd is not only overkill, it's also slower here.

Comment: 4x4 matrix fits easily to vector registers so vectorized multiplication could use registers as temporary storage for small matrices. But copy for a small matrix to a stack allocated space is also very fast because stack memory is very likely to be in L1 cache for very fast access making copy avoidance to be practically no gain optimization.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not thrilled with this answer (I'm posting it mainly to silence the "it obviously can't be done" crowd), but I'm skeptical that it's possible to do much better with a true in-place algorithm (O(1) extra words of storage for multiplying two n x n matrices). Let's call the two matrices to be multplied A and B. Assume that A and B are not aliased.

If A were upper-triangular, then the multiplication problem would look like this.

```
[a11 a12 a13 a14] [b11 b12 b13 b14]
[ 0  a22 a23 a24] [b21 b22 b23 b24]
[ 0   0  a33 a34] [b31 b32 b33 b34]
[ 0   0   0  a44] [b41 b42 b43 b44]
```

We can compute the product into B as follows. Multiply the first row of B by `a11`. Add `a12` times the second row of B to the first. Add `a13` times the third row of B to the first. Add `a14` times the fourth row of B to the first.

Now, we've overwritten the first row of B with the correct product. Fortunately, we don't need it any more. Multiply the second row of B by `a22`. Add `a23` times the third row of B to the second. (You get the idea.)

Likewise, if A were unit lower-triangular, then the multiplication problem would look like this.

```
[ 1   0   0   0 ] [b11 b12 b13 b14]
[a21  1   0   0 ] [b21 b22 b23 b24]
[a31 a32  1   0 ] [b31 b32 b33 b34]
[a41 a42 a43  1 ] [b41 b42 b43 b44]
```

Add `a43` times to third row of B to the fourth. Add `a42` times the second row of B to the fourth. Add `a41` times the first row of B to the fourth. Add `a32` times the second row of B to the third. (You get the idea.)

The complete algorithm is to LU-decompose A in place, multiply U B into B, multiply L B into B, and then LU-undecompose A in place (I'm not sure if anyone ever does this, but it seems easy enough to reverse the steps). There are about a million reasons not to implement this in practice, two being that A may not be LU-decomposable and that A won't be reconstructed exactly in general with floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: I don't follow you. when I LU factorize A, I have A = LU. How do you mean that you "LU-decompose A in place", without creating/allocating more space for L and or for U?

Comment: @flebool L and U are stored where A used to be, L below the main diagonal, U on and above the main diagonal.

Comment: I see, +1. Notice however that you call "LU-undecompose A in place" is far from a trivial step. For example if you try to do it as the simple matrix multiplication "LU" it is a simpler version of this same question, but again it is not feasible without caching.

Comment: @flebool I agree that it's somewhat sneaky, but it can be derived fairly straightforwardly from the in-place LU algorithm -- just do the inverse row-ops in reverse order.

Comment: This is impressive!  I'm not sure which of your answers to accept -- this one uses O(1) auxiliary space but the other is obviously better in practice.  I'm going to benchmark both of them (as well as just copying the whole matrix) and report back.

Comment: @TavianBarnes Don't bother implementing this one; it's going to be slower, due to its use of division and many more multiplications.

Comment: No doubt, I'm just curious by how much.  I'm dealing with affine transformation matrices so there may be a special form of the LU decomposition too.

Comment: I accepted this answer because I think it's closest to the ultimately correct answer of "it's possible, but probably not worth it"

Comment: A neat thing about this answer is that if one might just store relevant matrices in LU form. cuBLAS has fast triangular matrix multiplication functions, and you can store the LU form in a single square matrix like before. Seems pretty perfect really.

Comment: Link to cuBLAS triangle matrix multiplication (trmm) function with in-place support: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html?highlight=trmm#cublasxt-t-trmm

Answer (score 14):

This answer is more sensible than my other one, though it uses one whole column of additional storage and has the same amount of data movement as the naive copying algorithm. To multiply A with B, storing the product in B (again assuming that A and B are stored separately):

```
For each column of B,
    Copy it into the auxiliary storage column
    Compute the product of A and the auxiliary storage column into that column of B
```

I switched the pseudocode to do the copy first because for large matrices, caching effects may result in it being more efficient to multiply A by the contiguous auxiliary column as opposed to the non-contiguous entries in B.

Comment: Why are the transposes necessary?  Or do you mean to just transpose them conceptually?

Comment: I much prefer this answer, it can also be used for non-square matrices.  You just need your output matrix to have the same dimensionality as one of the input matrices.  Of course, if you switch B->A in your algorithm you need to switch column->row

Answer (score 0):

This answer is about 4x4 matrices. Assuming, as you propose, that `out` may reference either `lhs` or `rhs`, and that A and B have cells of uniform bit-length, in order to technically be able to perform the multiplication in place, elements of A and B, as signed integers, generally cannot be greater or smaller than `± floor (sqrt (2 ^ (cellbitlength - 1) / 4))`.

In this case, we can hack the elements of A into B (or vice versa) in the form of a bit shift or a combination of bit flags and modular arithmetic, and compute the product into the former matrix. If A and B were tightly packed, save for special cases or limits, we could not admit `out` to reference either `lhs` or `rhs`.

Using the naive method now would not be unlike David's second algorithm description, just with the extra column stored in A or B itself. Alternatively, we could implement the Strassen-Winograd algorithm according to the schedule below, again with no storage outside of `lhs` and `rhs`. (The formulation of `p0,...,p6` and `C` is taken from page 166 of Jonathan Golan's *The Linear Algebra a Beginning Graduate Student Ought to Know*.)

```
p0 = (a11 + a12)(b11 + b12), p1 = (a11 + a22)b11, p2 = a11(b12 - b22),
p3 = (a21 - a11)(b11 + b12), p4 = (a11 + a12)b22, p5 = a22(b21 - b11),
p6 = (a12 - a22)(b21 + b22)
    ┌                                      ┐
c = │ p0 + p5 - p4 + p6,      p2 + p4      │ 
    │   p1 + p5        , p0 - p1 + p2 + p3 │
    └                                      ┘
```

Schedule:

Each `p` below is a 2x2 quadrant; "x" means unassigned; "nc", no change. To compute each `p`, we use an unassigned 2x2 quadrant to superimpose the (one or) two results of 2x2 block matrix addition or subtraction, using the same bit-shift or modular method above; we then add their product (the seven multiplications resulting in single-elements) directly into the the target block in any order (note that for the 2x2-sized `p2` and `p4`, we use the southwest quadrant of `rhs`, which is no longer needed at that point). For example, to write the first 2x2-sized `p6`, we superimpose the block matrix subtraction, `rhs(a12) - rhs(a22)`, and block matrix addition, `rhs(b21) + rhs(b22)`, onto the `lhs21` submatrix; then add each of the seven single-element `p`'s for that block multiplication, `(a12 - a22) X (b21 + b22)`, directly to the `lhs11` submatrix.

```
LHS            RHS (contains A and B)

(1)
p6   x
x    p3

(2)
+p0  x
p0   +p0

(3)
+p5  x
p5   nc

(4)
nc   p1
+p1  -p1

(5)
-p4  p4        p4 (B21)
nc   nc

(6)
nc  +p2        p2 (B21)
nc  +p2
```