# Does `np.matmul(A, B, out=A)` multiply the matrices in-place?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, linear-algebra

I'm trying to understand how `out=` parameters work in numpy, pytorch and similar libraries.
Intuitively I would expect it to allow allocation free arithmetic. That is, where `C = A @ B` would allocate a new matrix, `np.matmul(A, B, out=C)` would use the space already allocated for `C`, thus requiring less memory management and faster code.

What confuses me is that the code
`np.matmul(A, B, out=A)` seems to work correctly.
That is, it computes `A = A @ B` without error.
So if this is really done without allocating new memory, then numpy (or pytorch) must be using some sort of in-place matrix multiplication algorithm. But I don't think those really exist? (See e.g. [Is there an algorithm to multiply square matrices in-place?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25450809/205521))

So am I wrong that `out=` doesn't allocate memory? Or is it just that numpy and pytorch are smart enough to realize that the output is the same as one of the inputs, and then allocates memory in this particular case?

I tried reading the documentation (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.matmul.html) but it doesn't give any details of what's really going on.

Comment: It could easily be implemented by allocating a temporary array internally that's a copy of `A`'s data, then performing the computation with `A` as the output only (they couldn't swap out the storage inside `A` because it might back other views). When there's little benefit or ability to operating in-place, all it needs to do is act *as if* it's operating in-place; if it's impossible to tell the difference (for any case where the extra temporary doesn't blow RAM, and it's not like Python is overly detailed about when it allocates memory), it's legal.

Comment: Yes, `numpy` is a special case because that's not Python memory.  The Python object is just a wrapper around numpy's C memory allocation.  So, unlike a typical Python function, it CAN tell whether the input and output matrices actually occupy the same memory.

Comment: Typically `numpy` calculations use a temporary buffer, even if the `out` is the same.  That is clearest when looking at the `at` method of `ufuncs`, (e.g. `np.add.at`), which explicitly avoids the buffering inherent in `x[...] += b`.  For speed `matmul` passes that action to BLAS like functions.  There may be versions that work in-place, but I doubt if `matmul` tries to use them.  The result shape of `matmul` is, in general, not the same of either argument.  So the value of a in-place branch would be pretty limited.

Comment: I guess I would like to know on which cases it allocates memory and in which it doesn't, so I can decide what makes sense

Comment: your case is just a special case which requires the matrices to be square, as a result the same memory allocated for A or B can be used to store the output. Try matrices that are not square and an error is raised for np.matmul(A, B, out=A). Computation-wise for matmul you always need a buffer to store the intermediate results (I cant think of a way you can do general matmul in-place). for computation time they seem to be the same.

Comment: I mean, if I do `np.matmul(A,B,out=C)`, can I expect it to not allocate a temporary array? Right now I wonder if "out=" ever actually works.